# Why does Dini's theorem apply here?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

When reading a textbook I encounter the following argument which I couldn't understand. The stochastic process $X$ below is assumed to be a Levy process, but we might not need this fact and might just take it as a stochastic process.

So the authors manage to prove that for any $n$ and $t \in [0,c]$, where $c$ is a constant, the following inequality hold:
$$
\lim_{s \rightarrow t} P(|X_c - X_s| \geq n) \leq P(|X_c - X_t| \geq n)
$$
Then they claim "by Dini's theorem" we can establish the following equality
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{0 \leq t \leq c}P(|X_c - X_t| \geq n) = 0
$$
I cannot see why Dini's theorem apply here: I suppose that the authors are suggesting that we consider the sequence of functions $f_n(t) = P(|X_c - X_t| \geq n)$ defined on the compact interval $[0,c]$. But they haven't established the *continuity* of these functions. I'm thereby confused and have been wondering if we don't need Dini's theorem to prove the desired equality?

Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality

$$\lim_{s \to t} \mathbb{P}(|X_c-X_s| \geq n) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X_c-X_t| \geq n)$$

shows that

$$f_n(t) := \mathbb{P}(|X_t-X_c| \geq n)$$

is upper semicontinuous; therefore the following version of Dini's theorem is applicable:

> Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of upper semicontinuous functions such that $f_n \geq f_{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 1$. If there exists a continuous function $f$ such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$, then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact sets.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Going to through the proof I realize that semi-continuity is really enough:-)

Comment: @Dormire You are welcome